# Insert Plugin information above or below the content

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I have designed a voting plugin for wordpress, user have to select up or down vote. Based on the selection using AJAX the vote count will be displayed. I need to add that voting images above or below the post.

I have tried using add_filter(the_content,fn); but voting plugin is using AJAX, so until the post load the vote increment is not displaying but vote get incremented.

But I tried by placing that HTML script in post.php that is template folder manually and it works fine.

Kindly suggest me how to write a function so that I can able to keep my html script after or before the post area, similar to adding manually to post.php.

Comment: The vote for that page increments without anyone clicking the upvote?

Comment: You *must* show the functions you're using, in the *most* reduced way as possible (http://sscce.org).

Comment: after user clicked the up vote, the values are updated[by watched in firebug] not updating in the display area. After reloading that post we can able to see the update..